# Calling a function in React: Uncaught TypeError: ...is not a function(…)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to add a User, and for now I am just trying to the calls to work, so there is no data being passed so far. Mycontainer looks like this:

user-add.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {createUser} from '../actions/index'

class UserCreate extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2> Add User </h2>

                <table className="userTable">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name:</td>
                    <td>Last Name:</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text"
                            placeholder="Hello!"
                            value="Val" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text"
                            placeholder="Hello!"
                            value="Val" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>


                <button onClick={() =>this.props.createUser()}>Submit</button>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        user: state.activeUser
    };
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({createUser: createUser}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserCreate);
```

In the reducer for my users, I have added the corresponding case to my switch statement:

```
switch (action.type) {
    case 'USER_DELETED':
        return state.filter(user => user.id !== action.userIdToDelete);
    case 'USER_CREATED':
        return state;
}
```

and of course I have also added the action to my actioncreators like so

```
export const createUser = () => {
    console.log("You created user: XX ");
    return {
        type: 'USER_CREATED',
        payload: {}
    }
};
```

However, it gives me:

> Uncaught TypeError: _this2.props.createUser is not a function(…)

Any ideas? I am very new to this, have posted here a few times already (other questions though), but I am not really understanding what's wrong.If you need any other code snippets, let me know and I'll post them. I know that the code posted is incomplete, just bear in mind that I just want the button to call the function etc., the actual creation of a user is another problem for now.

Comment: I deleted my comments, there's probably a Redux aspect to this that I'm unaware of. (I'm not familiar with Redux.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using `matchDispatchToProps` (which should be `mapDispatchToProps?`) anywhere.

You need to add it to your connect:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserCreate);
```

Comment: while it is called `matchDispatchToProps`, I did indeed not add it to my connect. this seems to have been the error! thanks

Comment: ah I see I had a typo myself in trying to correct OP, I was talking about `match` => `map`, `To` => `to` was an error on my part

Comment: @narvoxx: Ah!! I completely read past the `match`/`map`! :-) Thanks!